# Is it possible to install ImpressPages on IIS?

Tags: php, iis, impresspages

I have an IIS server. But ImpressPages doesn't work on it by default. Is there a way to make it working on IIS?

Answer (score 0):

ImpressPages doesn't run on IIS. But someone claims they have succeded: http://www.impresspages.org/cms/answers/5824/how-to-run-impresspages-on-iis-windows-server